# Reporting Services column visibility expression includes substring column names

Tags: reporting-services, substring

I have an SSRS 2012 report with columns that are to displayed or hidden based on user parameter selections.  Each column has a visibility expression associated with it.  For instance, the expression to show or hide the "Cash Flow" column is:

```
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!IF_Variables.Value,","),"CashFlow")>0,False,True)
```

The problem is that I also have a column called "AnnualCashFlow", with a corresponding visibility expression.  If the users selects it, the "CashFlow" column will also be displayed, even if it wasn't chosen, because it is a substring of the longer column name.

There are several other columns that are related in this way.  How can I formulate an expression that will only find the exact string requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the delimiter to help with this:

```
=IIF(InStr("," & JOIN(Parameters!IF_Variables.Value, ",") & ",", ",CashFlow,") >0
  ,False
  ,True)
```

Since this includes the delimiters in the check, this will match `CashFlow` only, and not when it's part of a longer string.

Say you have the `CashFlow` column and your parameter list is `Col1,Col2,AnnualCashFlow`. In the expression we are looking for `,CashFlow,` in the adjusted string `,Col1,Col2,AnnualCashFlow,` there is no match so the **Hidden** expression is working as required.